# 10 Month average

Tags: sql-server

I'm replacing an Excel spreadsheet with a Microsoft SQL Server 2008 database and need to calculate this:

```
=AVERAGE(IF((A:A>A4-304)*(A:A<=A4),G:G))
```

Where column A is the date and column G is the value.
The heading for this field is:

> 10 month simple moving average

I suppose I will use something like:

```
SELECT RawData.* 
,(SELECT Sum(X.AdjClose) AS SumAdjClose
    FROM RawData X
    WHERE DATEDIFF(d,X.RawDate,RawData.RawDate) <= 304
) AS SumAdjClose
FROM RawData
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server one option is to make the filters in the `WHERE` clause and the average in the `SELECT`

```
select  avg(ValueCol)
from    Table1
where   DateCol between @Date-304 and @Date
```

Another option, in the same logic of the excel could be:

```
select  avg(case when DateCol between @Date-304 and @Date then ValueCol else null)
from    Table1
```

Comment: I had to use "between DATEADD(d,-304,@Date) AND @Date", but thanks for your guidance!